# Relative path for std file streams

Tags: c++

Is it possible to provide a root folder and after this only relative paths for std::ifstream and std::ofstream?

For example:

```
SetFileStreamRootFolder("C:/");
std::ifstream stream("isample.txt"); //C:\isample.txt file
std::ofstream stream("osample.txt"); //C:\osample.txt file
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write a function, yes.
The `fstream`-objects do not impose anything on you, you can specify a relative path or an absolute path.

[Cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/open/) states:

```
Parameters:
filename

String with the name of the file to open.
Specifics about its format and validity 
depend on the library implementation and running environment.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define your own method which knows the working directory and prepends the correct string to the filename.

```
std::string prependFilePath(const std::string &filename);
```

Then construct a stream with

```
stream(prependFilePath("isample.txt").c_str());
```

---

Example:

```
std::string prependFilePath(const std::string &filename)
{
    // The path can be relative or absolute
    return "../" + filename;
}
```

In a real implementation, you should store the path (e.g.: `../`) in a `const std::string` member rather than hard-coding it and probably this method is a good candidate for getting a static modifier (real helper/utility method).

Answer (score 2):

Sure, using Boost.Filesystem

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
...
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;
fs::current_path("C:/");
```

Filesystem, or something like it, is slated for inclusion in the standard library.  VS2012 includes a preliminary implementation of it.  So if you don't have Boost, and you don't feel like installing it, you can use that.

```
#include <filesystem>
...
namespace fs = std::tr2::sys;
fs::current_path(fs::path("C:/"));
```

Comment: Thanks for adding the information about the `tr2` implementation.